# I cant communicate between two scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 files/scripts of code:

the first one:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float Speed = 15f;
    private PlayerController playerControllerScript;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerControllerScript = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(playerControllerScript.gameOver == false)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
        }

        //transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * Speed);

    }

}
```

the second one:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody playerRB;
    public float JumpForce = 150;
    public float GravityModifier;
    public bool OnTheGround = true;
    public bool gameOver;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Physics.gravity *= GravityModifier;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)&& OnTheGround)
        {
            playerRB.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            OnTheGround = false;
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            OnTheGround = true;
        }
        
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Obsticle"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Game over");
            gameOver = true;
        }
        
    }
}
```

So for my simple game, I need to check if the game over 'bool' is checked or not(true or false) then send the bool value to the first script. I have already tried this but I am repeatedly getting an error.

Please help me. I am not very good at programming.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you post it?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MoveLeft.Update () (at Assets/Course Library/scripts/MoveLeft.cs:18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you posted in the comments, there is a null reference in the `Update` method of your script `MoveLeft.cs`. The one reference that can be nullable in your `Update` is `playerControllerScript`. The error is specifying that the reference for `playerControllerScript` is not assigned, so it is null, meaning that accessing it will result in an error.

The line you are using to grab the reference, in theory, is correct:

```
GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
```

You are searching for an object named `Player` that has the script component called `PlayerController.cs`. The reference is not found due to no object in your scene being called `Player` or the object called `Player` does **not** have the script component `PlayerController.cs` attached to it. The object called `Player` must be in the same scene as your other object and it **must** have this script component attached. If a child object has the script, you can use [`Component.GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html).

Comment: Good answer. Just to pinpoint something. It's true that the object need to be in the same scene, but you can preserve objects from one scene to another by calling DontDestroyOnLoad on each object you want to preserve. This will "carry" object to any scene and "Find" method would work.

Answer (score -1):

In order to access the values of a class you need to instanciate an object of said class. Then you can access said values using it´s respective get and set methods.